# How to add Decimal Separator character to iOS keyboard Number Pad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I create a number pad with a decimal point separator character option in Xcode's Interface Builder Storyboard?

Changing `Keyboard Type` to `Number Pad` doesn't show a decimal option:

[image: Keyboard Type > Number Pad]

[image: Keyboard Type > Number Pad]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In iOS 4.1, there is a number pad with a decimal point available. You can select it programatically (in case you are supporting versions of iOS before 4.1) like so:

```
inputBoxTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
if (([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] >= 4.1)) {
    inputBoxTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
}
```

You could choose any appropriate keyboard type (line 1). In this case, NumbersAndPunctuation includes a period in case the user's iOS version is before 4.1.

Comment: You really only need to set the keyboard type once, so in your `viewDidLoad` method would probably be the right place.

Answer (score 7):

In Swift:

```
priceText.keyboardType = .decimalPad
```

Comment: Swift 4.0 :) priceText.keyboardType = .decimalPad

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 8 or above follow these steps:

1. Select the Textfield in Interface Builder
2. Edit `Keyboard Type` in xib or Storyboard
3. Select `Decimal Pad`

[image: Keyboard Type > Decimal Pad]

[image: Decimal Pad]

Answer (score 0):

I have developed an open source custom decimal keyboard. Methods and implementations are very easy to use and you can change buttons or add/remove extra buttons as you see fit. Please have at look at the repository here [TD-DecimalKeyboard](https://github.com/babaksamareh/TD-DecimalKeyboard) and feel free to fork and contribute.

[image: TD-DecimalKeyboard]